# if else statement after sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I have this query which searches for torrent_download, torrent_download can only be 1 or 0;

```
$sql_istorrenthere = $this->query("SELECT torrent_download
FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "auctions WHERE
                auction_id='" . $item_details['auction_id'] . "'"); 
if (empty($sql_istorrenthere))
{

        $display_output = GMSG_NOTORRENT;}
        else
        $display_output = GMSG_TORRENT;
}
```

What I want to do is replace the part with `if (empty($sql_istorrenthere))` with something like `if $sql_istorrenthere == 1 then  $display_output = GMSG_NOTORRENT; else $display_output = GMSG_TORRENT;`

how to do this?

Comment: `var_dump($sql_istorrenthere);`

Comment: @KarolyHorvath i get this on top of page resource(156) of type (mysql result) but no change in GMSG

Comment: How are you connecting to your database? You probably need to use something like `$row = $sqlistorrenthere->fetch_assoc(); var_dump ($row);` after doing `$this->query(...);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first have to fetch the result row, it's hard to tell how because you didn't tell us the framework / database abstraction layer you're using. Check the documentation, you want to fetch the result as an array or object.

For array:

Try to display the result with `var_dump`, if you succeeded, you will see an array with the key the `torrent_download` key. Then simply compare `$res['torrent_download']` with `1`.

Comment: ok i got it now, but it shows some gibberish on top of the webpage, how to remove this? it shows this array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "0" ["torrent_download"]=> string(1) "0" }